# Unity android build - unable to merge manifest files

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an android build from unity game. The build worked fine on Unity 5.5. Ever since I upgraded to 2017.2, the build fails and gives me error that its unable to merge android manifest files due to some conflict with a plugin manifest.

Following are the things I have tried

- Deleting either of the manifest files and build
- Deleting both the manifest files and build
- Remove conflicting nodes in xml and build
- Change value of conflicting nodes in xml to the same value

Every time I build, the files get written by conflicted values and it fails to build. Anyone good with unity android build, please suggest a solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because the two android manifest files conflict with each other. For example, a few weeks ago I got the same error when my minimum android API was 22 for one file and 24 for the other. So I would suggest comparing the two files line by line and looking for conflicting pieces of information. This may not work but it's worth trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Open all manifest files and check 
“minSdkVersion” and “targetSdkVersion”
All manifest should have same values of these variables